# declaring javascript object property with a function not working

Tags: javascript, object, defineproperty

I'm making a lame text-based game, and I made an object player like so:

```
var player = {
    displayText: "<span>you</span>",
    currentPosition: 0,
    level: 1,
    health: function() { return 10 + (this.level * 15) },
    strength: function() { return this.level * 5 },
    hitRating: 4
}
```

My understanding is that you can give an object a function as a property.

However, when I `alert(player.health)` I get:

```
function() { return 10 + (this.level * 15) }
```

What am I doing wrong? Are you not able to declare a object property that way? Is there a way to auto-generate the value of `player.health` any time it's called later on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`player.health` is a function. To call a function, you have to put `()` after it:

```
alert(player.health());
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to create property with accessor on JS object, proper way to do this is to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

In your case:

```
// original object
var player = {
    displayText: "<span>you</span>",
    currentPosition: 0,
    level: 1,
    // health: function() { return 10 + (this.level * 15) },
    strength: function() { return this.level * 5 },
    hitRating: 4
}

// create property with accessor method
Object.defineProperty(player, "health", {
    get: function () {
        return 10 + (player.level * 15)
    }
})

// call the property
alert(player.health);  // 25
player.level++;
alert(player.health);  // 40
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the function, `player.health()`