# how to use javascript Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, object, defineproperty

I looked around for how to use the [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method, but couldn't find anything decent.

Someone gave me [this snippet of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18523198/2476755):

```
Object.defineProperty(player, "health", {
    get: function () {
        return 10 + ( player.level * 15 );
    }
})
```

But I don't understand it. Mainly, the `get` is what I can't get (pun intended). How does it work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty
this is an excellent tutorial here.

Answer (score 537, accepted):

Since you asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18523070/343721), let's take it to step by step. It's a bit longer, but it may save you much more time than I have spent on writing this:

**Property** is an OOP feature designed for clean separation of client code. For example, in some e-shop you might have objects like this:

```
function Product(name,price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.discount = 0;
}

var sneakers = new Product("Sneakers",20); // {name:"Sneakers",price:20,discount:0}
var tshirt = new Product("T-shirt",10);  // {name:"T-shirt",price:10,discount:0}
```

Then in your client code (the e-shop), you can add discounts to your products:

```
function badProduct(obj) { obj.discount+= 20; ... }
function generalDiscount(obj) { obj.discount+= 10; ... }
function distributorDiscount(obj) { obj.discount+= 15; ... }
```

Later, the e-shop owner might realize that the discount can't be greater than say 80%. Now you need to find EVERY occurrence of the discount modification in the client code and add a line

```
if(obj.discount>80) obj.discount = 80;
```

Then the e-shop owner may further change his strategy, like *"if the customer is reseller, the maximal discount can be 90%"*. And you need to do the change on multiple places again plus you need to remember to alter these lines anytime the strategy is changed. This is a bad design. That's why ***encapsulation*** is the basic principle of OOP. If the constructor was like this:

```
function Product(name,price) {
  var _name=name, _price=price, _discount=0;
  this.getName = function() { return _name; }
  this.setName = function(value) { _name = value; }
  this.getPrice = function() { return _price; }
  this.setPrice = function(value) { _price = value; }
  this.getDiscount = function() { return _discount; }
  this.setDiscount = function(value) { _discount = value; } 
}
```

Then you can just alter the `getDiscount` (*accessor*) and `setDiscount` (*mutator*) methods. The problem is that most of the members behave like common variables, just the discount needs special care here. But good design requires encapsulation of every data member to keep the code extensible. So you need to add lots of code that does nothing. This is also a bad design, a *boilerplate antipattern*. Sometimes you can't just refactor the fields to methods later (the eshop code may grow large or some third-party code may depend on the old version), so the boilerplate is lesser evil here. But still, it is evil. That's why properties were introduced into many languages. You could keep the original code, just transform the discount member into a property with `get` and `set` blocks:

```
function Product(name,price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
//this.discount = 0; // <- remove this line and refactor with the code below
  var _discount; // private member
  Object.defineProperty(this,"discount",{
    get: function() { return _discount; },
    set: function(value) { _discount = value; if(_discount>80) _discount = 80; }
  });
}

// the client code
var sneakers = new Product("Sneakers",20);
sneakers.discount = 50; // 50, setter is called
sneakers.discount+= 20; // 70, setter is called
sneakers.discount+= 20; // 80, not 90!
alert(sneakers.discount); // getter is called
```

Note the last but one line: the responsibility for correct discount value was moved from the client code (e-shop definition) to the product definition. The product is responsible for keeping its data members consistent. Good design is (roughly said) if the code works the same way as our thoughts.

Alternatively, ES6 allows `class` syntax, which is a "special function" allowing the same functionality to code as:

```
class Product {
  constructor(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }
  #discount = 0; // # = private member in classes
  get discount() { return this.#discount; }
  set discount(v) { this.#discount = v; if(this.#discount>80) this.#discount = 80; }
}
```

So much about properties. But javascript is different from pure Object-oriented languages like C# and codes the features differently:

**In C#**, transforming fields into properties is a [breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/abhinaba/changing-a-field-to-a-property), so public fields should be coded as [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) if your code might be used in the separately compiled client.

**In Javascript**, the standard properties (data member with getter and setter described above) are defined by *accessor descriptor* (in the link you have in your question). Exclusively, you can use *data descriptor* (so you can't use i.e. *value* and *set* on the same property):

- **accessor descriptor** = get + set (see the example above)

  - ***get*** must be a function; its return value is used in reading the property; if not specified, the default is *undefined*, which behaves like a function that returns undefined
  - ***set*** must be a function; its parameter is filled with RHS in assigning a value to property; if not specified, the default is *undefined*, which behaves like an empty function
- **data descriptor** = value + writable (see the example below)

  - ***value*** default *undefined*; if *writable*, *configurable* and *enumerable* (see below) are true, the property behaves like an ordinary data field
  - ***writable*** - default *false*; if not *true*, the property is read only; attempt to write is ignored without error*!

Both descriptors can have these members:

- ***configurable*** - default *false*; if not true, the property can't be deleted; attempt to delete is ignored without error*!
- ***enumerable*** - default *false*; if true, it will be iterated in `for(var i in theObject)`; if false, it will not be iterated, but it is still accessible as public

<sup>* unless in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) - in that case JS stops execution with TypeError unless it is caught in [try-catch block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)</sup>

To read these settings, use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`.

Learn by example:

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o,"test",{
  value: "a",
  configurable: true
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o,"test")); // check the settings    

for(var i in o) console.log(o[i]); // nothing, o.test is not enumerable
console.log(o.test); // "a"
o.test = "b"; // o.test is still "a", (is not writable, no error)
delete(o.test); // bye bye, o.test (was configurable)
o.test = "b"; // o.test is "b"
for(var i in o) console.log(o[i]); // "b", default fields are enumerable
```

If you don't wish to allow the client code such cheats, you can restrict the object by three levels of confinement:

- **[Object.preventExtensions(yourObject)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions)** prevents new properties to be added to *yourObject*. Use `Object.isExtensible(<yourObject>)` to check if the method was used on the object. The prevention is *shallow* (read below).
- **[Object.seal(yourObject)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)** same as above and properties can not be removed (effectively sets `configurable: false` to all properties). Use `Object.isSealed(<yourObject>)` to detect this feature on the object. The seal is *shallow* (read below).
- **[Object.freeze(yourObject)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)** same as above and properties can not be changed (effectively sets `writable: false` to all properties with data descriptor). Setter's writable property is not affected (since it doesn't have one). The freeze is *shallow*: it means that if the property is Object, its properties ARE NOT frozen (if you wish to, you should perform something like "deep freeze", similar to [deep copy - cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/343721)). Use `Object.isFrozen(<yourObject>)` to detect it.

You don't need to bother with this if you write just a few lines fun. But if you want to code a game (as you mentioned in the linked question), you should care about good design. Try to google something about *antipatterns* and *code smell*. It will help you to avoid situations like *"Oh, I need to completely rewrite my code again!"*, it can save you months of despair if you want to code a lot. Good luck.

Comment: This portion is clear.

`function Product(name,price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  var _discount; // private member
  Object.defineProperty(this,"discount",{
    get: function() { return _discount; },
    set: function(value) { _discount = value; if(_discount>80) _discount = 80; }
  });
}
var sneakers = new Product("Sneakers",20);
sneakers.discount = 50; // 50, setter is called
sneakers.discount+= 20; // 70, setter is called
sneakers.discount+= 20; // 80, not 90!
alert(sneakers.discount); // getter is called`

Answer (score 27):

`get` is a function that is called when you try to read the value `player.health`, like in:

```
console.log(player.health);
```

It's effectively not much different than:

```
player.getHealth = function(){
  return 10 + this.level*15;
}
console.log(player.getHealth());
```

The opposite of get is set, which would be used when you assign to the value. Since there is no setter, it seems that assigning to the player's health is not intended:

```
player.health = 5; // Doesn't do anything, since there is no set function defined
```

A very simple example:

```js
var player = {
  level: 5
};

Object.defineProperty(player, "health", {
  get: function() {
    return 10 + (player.level * 15);
  }
});

console.log(player.health); // 85
player.level++;
console.log(player.health); // 100

player.health = 5; // Does nothing
console.log(player.health); // 100
```

Comment: it's just like a function that you don't need to actually use `()` to call... I don't understand what was the idea when they invented this thing. Functions are totally the same: https://jsbin.com/bugipi/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 20):

**defineProperty** is a method on Object which allow you to configure the properties to meet some criterias.
Here is a simple example with an employee object with two properties firstName & lastName and append the two properties by overriding the **toString** method on the object.

```
var employee = {
    firstName: "Jameel",
    lastName: "Moideen"
};
employee.toString=function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
console.log(employee.toString());
```

**You will get Output as : Jameel Moideen**

I am going to change the same code by using defineProperty on the object

```
var employee = {
    firstName: "Jameel",
    lastName: "Moideen"
};
Object.defineProperty(employee, 'toString', {
    value: function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    },
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
console.log(employee.toString());
```

The first parameter is the name of the object and then second parameter is name of the property we are adding , in our case it’s toString and then the last parameter is json object which have a value going to be a function and three parameters writable,enumerable and configurable.Right now I just declared everything as true.

If u run the example you will get Output as : **Jameel Moideen**

Let’s understand why we need the three properties such as **writable,enumerable and configurable.**

**writable**

One of the very annoying part of the javascript is , if you change the toString property to something else for example

[image]

if you run this again , everything gets breaks.
Let’s change writable to false. If run the same again you will get the correct output as ‘Jameel Moideen’ . This property will prevent overwrite this property later.

**enumerable**

if you print all the keys inside the object , you can see all the properties including toString.

```
console.log(Object.keys(employee));
```

[image]

if you set enumerable to false , you can hide toString property from everybody else. If run this again you will get firstName,lastName

**configurable**

if someone later redefined the object on later for example enumerable to true and run it. You can see toString property came again.

```
var employee = {
    firstName: "Jameel",
    lastName: "Moideen"
};
Object.defineProperty(employee, 'toString', {
    value: function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    },
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
});

//change enumerable to false
Object.defineProperty(employee, 'toString', {

    enumerable: true
});
employee.toString="changed";
console.log(Object.keys(employee));
```

[image]

you can restrict this behavior by set configurable to false.

[Orginal reference of this information is from my personal Blog](https://fromjami.com/2017/05/26/defineproperty-method-in-javascript/)

Comment: I get that you had this on your blog and just pasted it here, but at least know this for the future: screencaps are not popular on SO. You can't copypaste code to try it and the code won't be seen by search engines or assistive technology.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil You are right.i will update by add code instead of screen shot

Comment: Honestly, this answer was simple and made more sense than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `defineProperty` is a method that takes in 3 parameters - an object, a property, and a descriptor. What is happening in this particular call is the `"health"` property of the `player` object is getting assigned to 10 plus 15 times that player object's level.

Answer (score 0):

yes no more function extending for setup setter & getter 
this is my example **Object.defineProperty(obj,name,func)**

```
var obj = {};
['data', 'name'].forEach(function(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
        get : function() {
            return 'setter & getter';
        }
    });
});


console.log(obj.data);
console.log(obj.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.defineProperty() is a global function..Its not available inside the function which declares the object otherwise.You'll have to use it statically...

Answer (score 0):

### Summary:

```
Object.defineProperty(player, "health", {
    get: function () {
        return 10 + ( player.level * 15 );
    }
});
```

`Object.defineProperty` is used in order to make a new property on the player object. `Object.defineProperty` is a function which is natively present in the JS runtime environemnt and takes the following arguments:

`Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)`

1. The **object** on which we want to define a new property
2. The **name of the new property** we want to define
3. **descriptor object**

The descriptor object is the interesting part. In here we can define the following things:

1. **configurable** `<boolean>`: If `true`  the property descriptor may be changed and the property may be deleted from the object. If configurable is `false` the descriptor properties which are passed in `Object.defineProperty` cannot be changed.
2. **Writable** `<boolean>`: If `true` the property may be overwritten using the assignment operator.
3. **Enumerable** `<boolean>`: If `true`  the property can be iterated over in a `for...in` loop. Also when using the `Object.keys` function the key will be present. If the property is `false` they will not be iterated over using a `for..in` loop and not show up when using `Object.keys`.
4. **get** `<function>` : A function which is called whenever is the property is required. Instead of giving the direct value this function is called and the returned value is given as the value of the property
5. **set** `<function>` : A function which is called whenever is the property is assigned. Instead of setting the direct value this function is called and the returned value is used to set the value of the property.

### Example:

```js
const player = {
  level: 10
};

Object.defineProperty(player, "health", {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  get: function() {
    console.log('Inside the get function');
    return 10 + (player.level * 15);
  }
});

console.log(player.health);
// the get function is called and the return value is returned as a value

for (let prop in player) {
  console.log(prop);
  // only prop is logged here, health is not logged because is not an iterable property.
  // This is because we set the enumerable to false when defining the property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import { BLACK, BLUE, GREY_DARK, WHITE } from '../colours'

export const COLOR_ACCENT = BLUE
export const COLOR_DEFAULT = BLACK
export const FAMILY = "'Segoe UI', sans-serif"
export const SIZE_LARGE = '26px'
export const SIZE_MEDIUM = '20px'
export const WEIGHT = 400

type Font = {
  color: string,
  size: string,
  accent: Font,
  default: Font,
  light: Font,
  neutral: Font,
  xsmall: Font,
  small: Font,
  medium: Font,
  large: Font,
  xlarge: Font,
  xxlarge: Font
} & (() => CSSProperties)

function font (this: Font): CSSProperties {
  const css = {
    color: this.color,
    fontFamily: FAMILY,
    fontSize: this.size,
    fontWeight: WEIGHT
  }
  delete this.color
  delete this.size
  return css
}

const dp = (type: 'color' | 'size', name: string, value: string) => {
  Object.defineProperty(font, name, { get () {
    this[type] = value
    return this
  }})
}

dp('color', 'accent', COLOR_ACCENT)
dp('color', 'default', COLOR_DEFAULT)
dp('color', 'light', COLOR_LIGHT)
dp('color', 'neutral', COLOR_NEUTRAL)
dp('size', 'xsmall', SIZE_XSMALL)
dp('size', 'small', SIZE_SMALL)
dp('size', 'medium', SIZE_MEDIUM)

export default font as Font
```

Answer (score 0):

Defines a new property directly on an object, or modifies an existing property on an object, and return the object.

> Note: You call this method directly on the Object constructor rather
>   than on an instance of type Object.

```
   const object1 = {};
   Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', {
      value: 42,
      writable: false, //If its false can't modify value using equal symbol
      enumerable: false, // If its false can't able to get value in Object.keys and for in loop
      configurable: false //if its false, can't able to modify value using defineproperty while writable in false
   });
```

[image]

Simple explanation about define Property.

Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/manoj_antony32/pu5n61fs/

Answer (score 0):

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "last", {
  get: function() {
    if (this[this.length -1] == undefined) { return [] }
    else { return this[this.length -1] }
  }
});

console.log([1,2,3,4].last) //returns 4
```