# Pros and cons of this.myVar vs. var myVar

Tags: javascript

```
var MyFunction = function () {
    this.myVar = 'something';
    var myVar = 'else';
};
```

What are the pros and cons of the two above, I see them being used.

Comment: They're just different things. It's like asking the pros and cos of numbers vs strings.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález If you could give scenarios it would help as both can be used inside of the function just as well.

Comment: They are not interchangeable options, they do quite different things, so a pros and cons list doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It is not about pros and cons. It is about design, namely [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and [Encapsulation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18557503/343721). The latter link describes the third option you might find useful: properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is following:

```
var myFunc = function(){
this.x = 2; // You want this to be used outside of the declaration
}

var y = new MyFunc();
console.log(y.x); // 2

var myFunc2 = function(){
var x = 3; // you only want to use it inside this function
}

var z = new MyFunc2();
console.log(y.x); // undefined
```

So the this. variable will be accessible and the var won't be.

Comment: So it's basically public vs. protected/private in Java for example?

Comment: No it's closer to local vs (public) member

Comment: Just like Ilya said :)

Comment: ... but not exactly, because Javascript (closures, bindings, etc)

Comment: Will read up on it @Ilya

Answer (score 0):

Use this.myVar when you want to indicate that it is a variable that acts as a *property* of MyFunction.

Consider:

```
var MyFunction = function () {
this.myVar = 'something';
var myVar2 = 'else';
```

};

then

```
myF = new MyFunction()
```

Note that you can now access myF.myVar (as property), but not myVar2.

Comment: *"it is a variable that acts as a property of MyFunction"* - It's *not* a property of MyFunction, it's a property of whatever object `this` refers to when the function runs - which could be any object depending on how MyFunction was invoked.