# Injecting self-executing function as value in JS object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a simple library that will read values from an object given a string property.

Is it possible to read the property but have a function execute without actually invoking the function?

something like:

```
var obj = {

fn : (function malicious(){    deleteLotsOfFiles();
})()

}
```

if I do

```
var foo = obj.fn;
```

is there a way just by reading the property to execute a (malicious) function?

Comment: You can define a getter for a property using [MDN: Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) you could also look at that question [how to use javascript Object.defineProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524652/how-to-use-javascript-object-defineproperty)

Comment: Why would you not trust your arguments?

Answer (score 2):

The malicious function would have already executed anyway before you even referenced it. Once the function is parsed by the engine, it is executed straight away (self-invoking).

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {
    get fn() { deleteLotsOfFiles(); }
};

// later
var o = obj; // deleteLotsOfFiles has not been executed
console.log(o.fn); // you just deleted lots of files
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative

```
var o = Object.defineProperty(o, 'baz', {
    get: function(){
        console.log("Delete Everything!");
    } 
});
```

Then access `o.baz` and they are deleted

**More Information on getters from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)**

> Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a
>   dynamically computed value, **or you may want to reflect the status of
>   an internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method
>   calls.**

Seems pretty much like what you want to do.