# JavaScript: adding method to DOM-Object via prototype - like: Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, ...)

Tags: javascript, dom, methods, prototype, defineproperty

I want to **add some own methods** via `Object.prototype` to work easier with my `DOM objects`.

I found this on SO:

- [How do I write an extension method in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354298/how-do-i-write-an-extension-method-in-javascript)
  (SO link)
- [how to use javascript Object.defineProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524652/how-to-use-javascript-object-defineproperty) (SO link)

:

So I tried some code like this...

**js code** *(not working)*:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getSiblings', {
    value: (filteredByClassName) => {
        let siblings = [];
        let sibling = this.closest(filteredByClassName).firstChild;
        while (sibling) {
            if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling !== this && ((filteredByClassName)?(sibling.classList.contains(filteredByClassName)):true)) {
                siblings.push(sibling);
            }
            sibling = sibling.nextSibling
        }
        return siblings;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});

let activeCultureName = document.querySelector('.page .cultures.active p.name'); //important: source is not the ".culture" div element itself, it's a children (e.g. <p class="name">) of
let inactiveCultureSiblings = activeCulture.getSiblings('.culture'); //get all ".culture" div elements, instead of the active.
```

:

> **Problem** *(this is undefined)*:
>
> I can't access to the given object (via this), it's undefined. So I
>   can't use the closest() method.

:

**html code** *(for example)*:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="culture">
        <p class="name"> de-DE </p>
    </div>
    <div class="culture">
        <p class="name"> en-GB </p>
    </div>
    <div class="culture active">
        <p class="name"> en-US </p>
    </div>
    <div class="culture">
        <p class="name"> pl-PL </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

:

> **What I'm looking for:**
>
> I simply want to ask: `let mySiblings = domObject.getSiblings();` or with a
>   filter-query-param like: `let mySiblings =
>   domObject.getSiblings('.classname');`. So what I'm looking for is a
>   way to **add own methods/functions via prototype** to my dom objects.> I need some simple helper methods (like filter, siblings, toggle ...)
>   for my dom objects. The best way will be a

:

> **About me:**
>
> I'm a C#.NET Core developer, so usually I'm using extension methods (like
>   string extensions or what ever). In JS I've a little bit problems with
>   that mixed types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your function with a regular function instead of an arrow function.

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getSiblings', {
  value(filteredByClassName) {
    let siblings = [];

    // Now `this` will work
    let sibling = this.closest(filteredByClassName).firstChild;
    while (sibling) {
      if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling !== this && ((filteredByClassName)?(sibling.classList.contains(filteredByClassName)):true)) {
        siblings.push(sibling);
      }
      sibling = sibling.nextSibling
    }
    return siblings;
  },
  writable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```

Otherwise, `this` is bound to the lexical scope no matter what you do.

Comment: Yep, or you can use shorthand notation like I posted so you don't have to type that long `function` keyword.

Comment: Hi Jacob, you're totally right. :) 

`value: function(filteredByClassName) {...}`

This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jakob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119549/jacob) for giving the advice to relinquish the arrow function and set the "value" proberty as a function.

I also fixed the sibling finder method by className. It's only an example.
I think it may be more convenient to use a query statement (string) instead of a className (string) as filter parameter (method parameter).

So here's the full working code...

:

**js code**:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getSiblings', {
    value(filteredByClassName) {
        let closest = this.closest('.'+filteredByClassName);
        let siblings = [];
        let sibling = closest.parentElement.firstChild;
        while (sibling) {
            if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling !== this && ((filteredByClassName)?(sibling.classList && closest.classList!==sibling.classList && sibling.classList.contains(filteredByClassName)):true)) { //} && ((filteredByClassName)?(sibling.classList.contains(filteredByClassName)):true)) {
                siblings.push(sibling);
            }
            sibling = sibling.nextSibling
        }
        alert('siblings.length: '+siblings.length);
        return siblings;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});

let activeCultureName = document.querySelector('.page .cultures.active p.name');
let inactiveCultureSiblings = activeCulture.getSiblings('.culture');
```

:

**html code** *(for example)*:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="culture">
        <p class="name"> de-DE </p>
    </div>
    <div class="culture">
        <p class="name"> en-GB </p>
    </div>
    <div class="culture active">
        <p class="name"> en-US </p>
    </div>
    <div class="culture">
        <p class="name"> pl-PL </p>
    </div>
</div>
```